# How can I log JDBC database queries using java.util.logging?

Tags: java, logging, jdbc

I want to debug a few of my application JDBC queries so I wanted to configure java.util.logging to dump the actual SELECT statements that were run against the database and the data bound to their parameters.

I already have java.util.logging configured to log other messages to file. The setup code is as folloing:

```
Handler fh = new FileHandler("file.log", true);
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
fh.setFormatter(new GruposLogFormatter());
logger.addHandler(fh);
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
logger.info("==================================");
```

**So, how can I configure java.util.logging to log JDBC queries to a file or sysout?**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5738423/2839597) barely touches the subject, but didn't help me.

Comment: Just log the queries you run. You can't just intercept queries.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm having problems with the parameter binding, so I need to see what's going to the DB. I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure I've done this same thing with log4j and Spring a while ago, but now my setup is different.

Comment: Take a look at log4jdbc - http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Maybe I AM wrong. Now I remember that Hibernate was involved. Maybe I was getting Hibernate to log, not JDBC. Anyway, I was hoping I could pull it off without having to install a special driver or an external logging framework.

Comment: Actually, it would be helpful as well to know if what I want to do (log JDBC with JUL) is possible at al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate following configurations can be done to get the sql queries printed.

[How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values)

You can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/ also and intercept all queries and log them to a file

Comment: Right! I was refering to that exact Hibernate config in my comment to Sotirios. Too bad I'm not using Hibernate this time. Thanks anyway.