# Build query for jdbc but dont execute (or other solution to see post param-substituted query)

Tags: spring, jdbc, db2, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Im trying to degub a program using Springs's jdbcTemplate and I would really like to view the query. Is there any way to either use the debugger or a db2 watcher to see the outgoing/incoming queries?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JDBC logging to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738181/jdbc-logging-to-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the JDBC trace, e.g. by adding the property `traceFile=/path/to/trace.file;` to your JDBC URL. More details: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/t0020709.html?lang=en

Keep in mind that it affects the driver performance, obviously.