# How to enable oracle jdbc logging?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have done the below, but I do not see any jdbc logging:

- set my class path so the only jdbc jar is odjbc6_g.jar
- added to my vm arguments

> -Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/OracleLog.properties

my OracleLog.properties file

```
.level=SEVERE oracle.jdbc.level=INFO 
oracle.jdbc.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler 
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO 
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Any suggestions of anything else I should try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable logging for JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060563/enable-logging-for-jdbc)

Comment: You are doing basically [everything right](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/diagnose.htm#JJDBC28886). The only suspect thing is the line `oracle.jdbc.level=INFO` which is in all examples placed as a new line.

Comment: Note also, that the driver logging is rather technical and some experience is required to read it. If you are interested more in the *logical* view of the JDBC access, check the duplicated question mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem using your `properties` file

```
.level=SEVERE oracle.jdbc.level=ALL
oracle.jdbc.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

I receive only

```
 Bad level value for property: .level
```

You must use this properies file (note the new line after `SEVERE`)

```
.level=SEVERE 
oracle.jdbc.level=ALL
oracle.jdbc.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```