# Instrumenting JDBC driver to log SQL queries

Tags: jdbc

I am trying to automatically build (with mvn) and instrument some java projects where the JDBC drivers are instrumented to log all sql queries. Can anyone point me to any resources for how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060563/how-to-enable-logging-for-sql-statements-when-using-jdbc