# JDBC login that asks user to re-enter username and password if not found in database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So I am trying to practice working with databases and I decided to make a Banking System. I am using MariaDB. **I wanted to make it so the user can login and if the info doesnt match anything in the database, they have to re-enter the username and password until it matches** but I cannot figure it out. This is my first time implementing sql into java so I apologize if i made any mistakes. I have researched, but the solutions I could find were using swing or javafx but i am not looking to make a gui right now. Anyway, I am not really sure what I am doing in this part.

```
public void loginAccount(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        String login;
        ResultSet rs;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
            Username = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
            Password = in.nextLine();

            login = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Username = ? AND AccPassword = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(login);

            ps.setString(1, Username);
            ps.setString(2, Password);

            rs = ps.executeQuery(login);

        }   while (!rs.next());
    }
```

I keep getting **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND AccPassword = ?' at line 1**

Also, I originally had

`login = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Username = " +Username+ " AND AccPassword = " + Password;`

But i read somewhere that it is bad practice to use +. Not sure if that is true or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You intended to call [`PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery())

```java
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

but instead you called a static method [`Statement.executeQuery(String sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String))

```java
rs = ps.executeQuery(login);
```

Comment: thank you :) i didnt know this. The error went away, but i found that the loop keeps asking for username and password even if it matches the database. Might there be something wrong with my while(!rs.next())?

Comment: I cant see any obvious error. Try logging db statements (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060563/how-to-enable-logging-for-sql-statements-when-using-jdbc). And never keep passwords in plain text!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong method of PreparedStatement.

You should use

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

so that your statement gets executed where the placeholders actually have values.